# PHP to insert into a database error

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am trying to debug a program of mine, It is a simple PHP code for inserting into a database.

Whenever I run this in my browser :

```
http://localhost:3456/maps/savemdata.php?descr=Best&lat=-37.12345&lng=122.12345
```

It should Insert the values into the DB, but what I get is :

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'desc, lat, lng ) VALUES ('Best', '-37.12345', '122.12345' )'
>   at line 1

***Savemdata.php***

```
<?php
$hostname = '127.0.0.1:3306';        
$dbname   = 'login'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

// Gets data from URL parameters
$desc = $_GET['descr'];
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];


// Insert new row with user data
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO markers " .
         " (desc, lat, lng ) " .
         " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s' );",
         mysql_real_escape_string($desc),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lng));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved keyword and happens to be the name of your column. To avoid syntax error, you need to escape it using backtick. eg,

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `markers` " .
     " (`desc`, `lat`, `lng` ) " .
     " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s' );",
     mysql_real_escape_string($desc),
     mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
     mysql_real_escape_string($lng));
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the column name to which is not a reserved keyword to avoid problem from occurring again.

Comment: so this works , One part of the problem is solved..!! now I can enter the long, lat in the db but it still won't enter the description from the main page where I made the form, would you have a look at it

[Click This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976375/map-marker-to-database-in-mysql)

Comment: @rahul888 - Glad to hlep you. I have added answer over there it might helps you.

Answer (score 4):

DESC is a keyword in mysql. You should take it in backticks ;)

Comment: Actually it should be in backticks.

Comment: ``DESC`` is the answer.=D

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, i would suggest you to use PDO. Try changing your code in the below way.

```
<?php
$hostname = '127.0.0.1:3306';        
$dbname   = 'login'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = ''; 

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

// new data
$desc = $_GET['descr'];
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO markers  (desc,lat,lng) VALUES (:desc,:lat,:lng)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':desc'=>$desc,
                  ':lat'=>$lat,
                  ':lng'=>$lng));


?>
```

Comment: Yes or he should use mysqli.

Comment: This will also give error because `desc` is not inside backticks.